# hglib-python commit test case

Tags: mercurial

I am writing `hglib-erlang` for converting `hglib-python` to erlang language module. In the file of `"test-push.py"`, there is one test case as follows.

I think the second `commit('second')` will have nothing to commit and give error message. There is only one log item `('first')`. Is it right?

```
class test_push(common.basetest):
    def test_basic(self):
        self.append('a', 'a')
        self.client.commit('first', addremove=True)

        self.client.clone(dest='other')
        other = hglib.open('other')

        # broken in hg, doesn't return 1 if nothing to push
        #self.assertFalse(self.client.push('other'))

        self.append('a', 'a')
        self.client.commit('second')

        self.assertTrue(self.client.push('other'))
        self.assertEquals(self.client.log(), other.log())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a cursory reading of this test code, it would seem like `self.append('a', 'a')` makes changes to the virtual copy, so that `self.client.commit('second')` will just work as normal.

Comment: I understand it's my problem now. Previously, I implement append/2 function by deleting and adding new file everytime. So commit/1 function replies with "no change" for the second commit/1.